# How to extract common `yq` to keep script DRY?

Tags: yq

I have the following (modified from from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70152440/807037):

```
yq eval-all '
    .clusters = ( 
        (   
            (.clusters[] | {.name: .}) as $item ireduce ({}; . * $item)
        ) as $uniqueMap |
        ( $uniqueMap  | to_entries | .[]) as $item ireduce([]; . + $item.value)
    ) | 
    .contexts = ( 
        (
            (.contexts[] | {.name: .}) as $item ireduce ({}; . * $item)
        ) as $uniqueMap |
        ( $uniqueMap  | to_entries | .[]) as $item ireduce([]; . + $item.value)
    ) | 
    select(fi == 0)' konfig monfig
```

How can the following common code be extracted so as to keep the script DRY:

```
.«KEY» = (
        (
            (.«KEY»[] | {.name: .}) as $item ireduce ({}; . * $item)
        ) as $uniqueMap |
        ( $uniqueMap  | to_entries | .[]) as $item ireduce([]; . + $item.value)
    )
```

Input files:

```
# konfig
apiVersion: apiVersion-keep
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: cad-0
    server: server-0
  name: name-0
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: cad-1-discard
    server: server-1-discard
  name: name-1
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: cad-2
    server: server-2
  name: name-2
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster-0
    user: user-0
  name: name-0
- context:
    cluster: cluster-1-discard
    user: user-1-discard
  name: name-1
- context:
    cluster: cluster-2
    user: user-2
  name: name-2
current-context: name-keep
```

```
# monfig
apiVersion: apiVersion-discard
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: cad-1-keep
    server: server-1-keep
  name: name-1
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster-1-keep
    user: user-1-keep
  name: name-1
current-context: name-discard
```

Expected:

```
apiVersion: apiVersion-keep
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: cad-0
    server: server-0
  name: name-0
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: cad-1-keep
    server: server-1-keep
  name: name-1
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: cad-2
    server: server-2
  name: name-2
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster-0
    user: user-0
  name: name-0
- context:
    cluster: cluster-1-keep
    user: user-1-keep
  name: name-1
- context:
    cluster: cluster-2
    user: user-2
  name: name-2
current-context: name-keep
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is a little trickier than it appears because a use case for `|=` is  updating each matching left hand side node with respect to itself. `.clusters` results in two nodes (as with `.contexts`) and each of those nodes is updated independently. `yq` doesn't know to group the nodes together. After playing around a little I got this to work:

```bash
./yq eval-all '
  . ref $r |
  with( ("clusters", "contexts"); 
    $r[.] = ( 
        (
            ($r[.] | .[] | {.name: .}) as $item ireduce ({}; . * $item)
        ) as $uniqueMap |
        ( $uniqueMap  | to_entries | .[]) as $item ireduce([]; . + $item.value)
    )
  ) | select(fi==0)' file1.yaml file2.yaml
```

Explanation:

- `. ref $r` Create a reference to the root context, called `$r`. This matches the top level nodes (file1 and file2).
- Using the `with` operator, I can parameterise the merge expression against `$r`, passing in the two paths that need to be merged. Each path is run against the root context `$r` in `$r[.]`.

Hope that makes sense!

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking (due to missing sample data), you can use the [update operator](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/assign-update) `|=` (available since [v4.3.0](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.3.0)), enabling you to address by context `.` on the RHS. Then, as the absolute context only appears on the LHS, you can just list at once all contexts you want this to be applied to.

```bash
(.clusters, .contexts) |= ( .[] | ... )
```

Comment: I've added input and expected to the question. The answer provided _looks_ like it should work but it doesn't. it winds up discarding everything in `monfig`.

Comment: Replacing `=` with `|=` (and making other relevant changes) in the script in the question also doesn't work I'm thinking because it's using a reference to each file's entity rather than creating a new one.