# Merging multiple YAML files, but keeping all values in case there are multiple

Tags: yq

Assuming I have the following YAML files:

file1.yaml

```yaml
A:
  a:
    a1: value1
  b: value2
B:
  b: value3
```

file2.yaml

```yaml
A:
  a:
    a1: value2
```

file3.yaml

```yaml
A:
  a:
    a1: value3
```

How can I merge them, **but either have a key in it multiple times or have the values separates by e.g. a comma** using Mike Farah's [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (v4.31.2 on Apple Silicon architecture)?

I can easily merge them using the following shell command:

```bash
yq ea '. as $item ireduce({}; . * $item)' file*.yaml
```

However: `A.a.a1` equals to `value3` only.

So the *current* output is:

```yaml
A:
  a:
    a1: value3
  b: value2
B:
  b: value3
```

The **desired output** is either:

```yaml
A:
  a:
    a1: value1,value2,value3
  b: value2
B:
  b: value3
```

or:

```yaml
A:
  a:
    a1:
      - value1
        value2
        value3
  b: value2
B:
  b: value3
```

*Please note:* these are simple examples. I have far more files and they are much more complex. However, I will most likely only have string values, that I either need to append to an existing value or create a new key for.

Comment: Your desired merging technique is conceptually inconsistent (or at least incomplete) as it resolves the collision of key paths in creating an array on a (seemingly) arbitrary level. What determines that the given example should be resolved exactly on level `.A.a.a1` (you may just as well create an array (of objects) on levels `.A` or `.A.a` which collide just the same). You may argue with iterables vs scalars, but then what if there's a fourth file containing `.A.a.a1.a2 = "value4"`. Should it produce nested arrays, a flattened array, preserve deeper objects, and why only below `.A.a.a1`?

Comment: Therefore, to (consistently) produce your desired output, you have to introduce more constraints, either by explicitly regarding certain levels in your document tree (e.g. merge on all third levels, or provide `.A.a.a1` as done with `.services` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69246180)), or (more abstractly) by explicating specific structural constellations (e.g. overwrite in the usual way unless the key is named `"a1"`, or generally exclude mixed-type collisions by asserting a consistent maximum depth for colliding paths, then merge on common deepest level, etc.).

Comment: Thank you, these are good questions indeed and I must say I don't have an answer. What I am doing, is merging two or more values.yaml files (Helm Charts) and if I have same keys, but different values, I don't want to just override them. So I guess I cannot leave this complexity out, because it might help create constraints.