# Merge Two Yaml Files Deeply in Bash yq

Tags: bash, merge, yaml, yq

I have two yaml files:

file1.yaml

```
name: "name-a"
namespace: "name-a-space"

livenessProbe:
  path: is-alive

readinessProbe:
  path: is-ready

env:
  - name: key1
    value: test1
  - name: key2
    value: test2
  - name: KEY3
    value: test2
```

and file2.yaml

```
name: "name-b"
namespace: "name-b-space"

livenessProbe:
  path: is-alive1

readinessProbe:
  path: is-ready1

env:
  - name: key1
    value: test7
```

And to merge file1.yaml and file2.yaml I'm using yq v4.30.8

yq '. *= load("file2.yml")' file1.yml based on this [reference](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge)

The problem is that regarding env key it overwriting all elements of env in file2 on file1, but I need to to just overwrite the different value of key1
so the output should be

```
name: "name-b"
namespace: "name-b-space"

livenessProbe:
  path: is-alive1

readinessProbe:
  path: is-ready1

env:
  - name: key1
    value: test7
  - name: key2
    value: test2
  - name: KEY3
    value: test2
```

But my code generate

```
name: "name-b"
namespace: "name-b-space"

livenessProbe:
  path: is-alive1

readinessProbe:
  path: is-ready1

env:
  - name: key1
    value: test7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `*d` to [Merge, deeply-merging arrays](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-deeply-merging-arrays) which merges arrays "like objects, with indices as their key", i.e. "merge the first item in the array and do nothing with the [other ones].":

```bash
yq '. *d load("file2.yaml")' file1.yaml
```

```yaml
name: "name-b"
namespace: "name-b-space"
livenessProbe:
  path: is-alive1
readinessProbe:
  path: is-ready1
env:
  - name: key1
    value: test7
  - name: key2
    value: test2
  - name: KEY3
    value: test2
```

---

As it [turned out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76352612/merge-two-yaml-files-deeply-in-bash-yq/76352682?noredirect=1#comment134642624_76352682), you want the arrays in `.env` to be merged by matching a specific field within the item objects. To this end, you could `ireduce` the `.env` array into one object using `.name` as field names (which becomes the "key" when merging) using `.[] as $item ireduce ({}; .[$item.name] = $item.value)`. Do this for `.env` on both sides, then use regular merging with `*`. Eventually, `map` the indexed object back into your original array structure using `map({"name": key, "value": .})` (using unnecessary spaces to highlight duplicate code):

```bash
yq '
  (                     .env |= (.[] as $item ireduce ({}; .[$item.name] = $item.value))) *
  (load("file2.yaml") | .env |= (.[] as $item ireduce ({}; .[$item.name] = $item.value)))
  |                     .env |= map({"name": key, "value": .})
' file1.yaml
```

Also, take a look at how to [Merge arrays of objects together, matching on a key](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/multiply-merge#merge-arrays-of-objects-together-matching-on-a-key) in the manual, which is based on the question [How to Add / Replace array elements with "yq" conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69246180/how-to-add-replace-array-elements-with-yq-conditionally).

Finally, also consider using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (which is ["the other"](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info)  implementation of yq), or [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq). Both are YAML processors with the former internally translating to JSON, then using [stedolan/jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) under the hood, and the latter being a reimplementation of jq in Go, implementing native YAML functionality. Thus, both can make use of jq features not (yet) implemted by mikefarah/yq. For example:

```bash
# using kislyuk/yq
yq -sy '
  map(.env |= INDEX(.name)) | .[0] * .[1] | .env |= map(.)
' file1.yaml file2.yaml

# using itchyny/gojq
gojq -s --yaml-input --yaml-output '
  map(.env |= INDEX(.name)) | .[0] * .[1] | .env |= map(.)
' file1.yaml file2.yaml
```

Comment: Thank you @pmf, yes it is working,
But I tried another scenario where I just removed everything except the env in both files, but the behavior some how is weird

file1.yaml
env:
  - name: key1
    value: test1
  - name: key2
    value: test2
  - name: KEY3
    value: test2

file2.yaml 
env:
  - name: KEY3
    value: test8
  - name: key2
    value: test9

The output was as the following:

env:
  - name: KEY3
    value: test8
  - name: key2
    value: test9
  - name: KEY3
    value: test2

Key1 is missing and key3 duplicated

Comment: @AlbaraaKefaya `.env` is a regular array, and its items are regular objects with two fields `.name` and `.value`. There is no "indexing" of any kind where deduplication of some dedicated IDs could happen automatically. "Merging arrays" in the sense of `*d` works "like objects, with indices as their key", so same positions get overwritten. This is what happened in your question's sample data, and what happens with your comment's data. To specifically consider some arbitrary field as index (which you should have mentioned explicitly) you need to elevate it accordingly with some different logic.